# How many people need to call to make a bet on a flush draw worthwhile?

Tags: texas-hold-em, odds, pot-odds, flush, implied-odds

In Texas Hold'Em, after the flop, let's say you are holding two spades, and the flop comes out with two spades.  Now you have a flush draw.

How many people need to call your bet in order for there to be the correct odds for the bet to be statistically worthwhile?

To keep things simple and remove variables, let's assume no one will be folding and no one will be re-raising.

Comment: You'll need to add more details to get a specific answer. How many players are in the hand, what's the pot size, the bet size, stack sizes, your position. In general, the odds of hitting your draw are known, and you need close to those odds to call.

Comment: Also, table image, implied odds, perceived image, tournament-cash format, opponents styles & hand ranges, etc. are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer currently posted is incorrect.

In the situation posed:

- If you bet x, and 1 person calls, then you need over 50% odds for a
  worthwhile bet.
- If you bet x, and 2 people call, then you need over 33% odds for a
  worthwhile bet.

Since catching a flush in the defined situation has about a 35% chance, then you need 2 people to call for the bet to be worthwhile.

In the situation specified, the pot size is irrelevant.

Whether or not you want to make a statistically worthwhile bet will be based on many factors, including relative size of your chip stack.

Comment: You still don't get this concept of you win the pot.  What is in the pot is dead money.  Simple established poker math.

Comment: @paparazzo Please do move on like you promised before.  Your comments are not helpful or educational.  Saying things like "Do you not get..." is inflammatory and rude.  There is a "Be nice" philosophy on StackExchange, and it would be good if you could follow that philosophy.

Comment: Let me get this straight?   On the river there is $100 in the pot and you bet $1.  If you get 1 caller you need 50%?   You risked $1 for a 50% chance at $102.  Your EV is -1? + .5x$102 = $50.  If you solve for what you odds need to be   0 = -1$ + odds x 102.  Only need odds of 1 /102.   It is not a side bet for that betting round.  You win what is in the pot.  The pot IS relevant.  Unless you have the nuts you want no one to call and 100% chance of picking up $100 pot.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the bet.  If you bet 20% of the pot you only need one caller.

If you get 5 callers then you can bet like the pot.

You cannot remove the variable of they can raise your bet.

A better question would be call closing action.